# JavaScript and HTML: audio that overlap eachother

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback, pause

I'm working for studies purposes on a web site that can help people with  visual impairment. The site has to play  audio files thanks to keyboard's buttons. My problem is: when I play an audio (for example audio1)  and then I play another one (for example audio2), the two audio overlap eachother. My idea is to stop an audio using another button, for example X. So, if audio1 is playing and I press X, then audio1 should stop. I'll add my code here.
Thanks.

```
// HTML:
<audio src="audio/homepage_benvenuto.mp3" autoplay>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_0.mp3" id="audio0">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_1.mp3" id="audio1">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_2.mp3" id="audio2">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_3.mp3" id="audio3">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_4.mp3" id="audio4">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_5.mp3" id="audio5">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_6.mp3" id="audio6">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_7.mp3" id="audio7">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_8.mp3" id="audio8">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_9.mp3" id="audio9">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
        <audio src="audio/homepage_I.mp3" id="audioI">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
    
    // JavaScript:
    var source = "audio/homepage_benvenuto.mp3"
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.load()
    audio.addEventListener("load", function() 
    { 
        audio.play(); 
    }, true);
    audio.src = source;
   
    function checkKeyPressed(e) 
    {
        var player;

        if (e.keyCode == "48") // 48 = 0
        {
            document.getElementById('audio0').play()
            player = document.getElementById('audio0');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "49") // 49 = 1
        {
            document.getElementById('audio1').play()
            player = document.getElementById('audio1');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "50") // 50 = 2
        {
            document.getElementById('audio2').play()
            player = document.getElementById('audio2');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "51") // 51 = 3
        {
            document.getElementById('audio3').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio3');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "52") // 52 = 4
        {
            document.getElementById('audio4').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio4');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "53") // 53 = 5
        {
            document.getElementById('audio5').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio5');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "54") // 54 = 6
        {
            document.getElementById('audio6').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio6');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "55") // 55 = 7
        {
            document.getElementById('audio7').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio7');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "56") // 56 = 8
        {
            document.getElementById('audio8').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio8');
        }
        if (e.keyCode == "57") // 57 = 9
        {
            document.getElementById('audio9').play();
            player = document.getElementById('audio9');
        } 
      // Here I tried to create a script to stop the audio, but it doesn't work
         if (e.keyCode == "88") // 88 = X: interrompe audio in corso
        {
            player.pause();
            player.currentTime = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I have taken a look into your code, but the problem is that you store your 'player' variable inside of your checkKeyPressed(e) method. So each time you call the checkKeyPressed method your variable player will be reset, because at the beginning of the method you redeclare it with 'var player;'.

To fix this make sure the player variable is outside of your method like this:

```
var player = null;
    
    function checkKeyPressed(e) 
    {

    if (e.keyCode == "48") // 48 = 0
    {
        document.getElementById('audio0').play()
        player = document.getElementById('audio0');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "49") // 49 = 1
    {
        document.getElementById('audio1').play()
        player = document.getElementById('audio1');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "50") // 50 = 2
    {
        document.getElementById('audio2').play()
        player = document.getElementById('audio2');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "51") // 51 = 3
    {
        document.getElementById('audio3').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio3');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "52") // 52 = 4
    {
        document.getElementById('audio4').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio4');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "53") // 53 = 5
    {
        document.getElementById('audio5').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio5');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "54") // 54 = 6
    {
        document.getElementById('audio6').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio6');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "55") // 55 = 7
    {
        document.getElementById('audio7').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio7');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "56") // 56 = 8
    {
        document.getElementById('audio8').play();
        player = document.getElementById('audio8');
    }
  // Here I tried to create a script to stop the audio, but it doesn't work
     if (e.keyCode == "88") // 88 = X: interrompe audio in corso
    {
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = 0;
    }
    }
```

Little side note: I see you are using e.keyCode == "88" to pause your music. This means you have to use the combination Shift + x to pause the music instead of only pressing x on your keyboard.